# AutocompleteInput suggestions are not working

Tags: autocomplete, react-admin

I'm working on a project in react-admin and am trying to use an AutocompleteInputs within ReferenceInputs for Filter in a List. The list is a product that has a relationship with two different users, a consumer and provider. I'm currently able to obtain the choices for consumers and providers and filter my product list by either.

However, my issues arises with the autosuggestion. It's simply not working. Typing in the AutocompleteInput will not filter the choices to select from for either consumers or providers. I have another AutocompleteArrayInput within an ArrayReferenceInput for providers that's setup similarly and the autosuggestion is working perfectly fine.

Any thoughts?

Here's the broken AutocompleteInput:

```
export const ProductFilter = props => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <ReferenceInput label="Consumer" reference="consumers"  
    source="consumer_user_id" allowEmpty>
      <AutocompleteInput source="id" optionText={FullNameRenderer} />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <ReferenceInput label="Provider" reference="providers" 
    source="provider_user_id" alwaysOn allowEmpty>
      <AutocompleteInput optionText={FullNameRenderer} />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <DateRangeInput alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
)
```

And this is the working AutocompleteArrayInput:

```
export const ConsumerEdit = props => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <TabbedForm redirect="show">
      <FormTab label="Providers" path="provider_assignmenmts">
        <ReferenceArrayInput label='Assigned Providers' 
        reference='providers' defaultValue={[]} 
        source="provider_ids" allowEmpty>
          <AutocompleteArrayInput optionText={FullNameRenderer}/>
        </ReferenceArrayInput>
      </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
  </Edit>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like this one is a larger issue within react-admin.

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3098

Answer (score 0):

In the component `<AutocompleteInput source = "id" optionText = {FullNameRenderer} />` the attribute source = "id" is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. I added that in my attempts to get the autosuggestions working, but was obviously unsuccessful.